# How do I ensure that I am dynamically linking my application to the Qt framework in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt

How do I ensure that I am dynamically linking my application to the Qt framework in Qt Creator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Click the "Projects" sidebar item and in the Build Settings tab, see what Qt version you are linking against.

Chances are, you're linking against the version which came with Qt when you installed it, which is dynamic. If you've made your own static build of Qt, this is where you switch between them.